# How to name an event describing the acknowledgment of the existence of an entity in an event sourced system?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I am new to Event Sourcing and I am considering using it for an industrial application to track events happening in a production facility.

Since the book of record is the production facility itself and not the system, and also because not everything is automated, workers will need to report at a given point in time (the recorded time) what they did at another point in time (the effective time). Therefore, I will be using events such as: `TankFilledRecorded`, `TankOutputConnectedToPipeInputRecorded`, `ContainerMovedToFacilityAreaRecorded`, etc. where these events refer to entities such as a tank, a pipe, or a facility area for example. These events will have both a *recorded* time and an *effective* time. Note that there is no submission or approval process for a record to be considered legit.

Domain-driven design (DDD) encourages to design events that are representative of what happens in the domain (like the ones above).
However, in my domain, I don’t care so much about how a tank, a pipe or a facility area came to existence. I just need to know that something exists from a particular point in time, and I also need to know if it is not there after a particular point in time. The main objective of the software is to track liquids and powders flowing in a circuit made of these pipes, tanks and other components. It is not an asset management system and should not become one.

Therefore, what would be the correct DDD way to design an event that represents the fact that there is a tank, a pipe or an area in the production facility?

It is a subtle question but language is important, particularly in DDD.

Here is what I came up with:

### 1 `EntityExistenceAcknowledgmentRecorded`

```
TankExistenceAcknowledgmentRecorded
PipeExistenceAcknowledgmentRecorded
FacilityAreaExistenceAcknowledgmentRecorded
TankDisappearanceAcknowledgmentRecorded
PipeDisappearanceAcknowledgmentRecorded
FacilityAreaDisappearanceAcknowledgmentRecorded
```

It seems awful to use this in the ubiquitous language. I don’t see myself talking in these terms or providing a UI with such vocabulary. But it does represent exactly what happens though.

### 2 `EntityRegistered`

```
TankRegistered
PipeRegistered
FacilityAreaRegistered
TankUnregistered
PipeUnregistered
FacilityAreaUnregistered
```

It seems much simpler and it also seems to be meaningful except for one thing. “Registered” conveys the existence of the representation of an entity in the system with *immediate effect*, without the possibility of saying now that the entity existed 2 days ago. Think about a `UserRegistered` event in a website that would indicate that the user “existed” from 10 days ago. What would that even mean?

Events are facts and you cannot change the past. However, I do need a way for my users to invalidate a record in which they made a mistake such as a typo. They can record now that they acknowledged the existence of a facility area a week ago and might realize later than there was something wrong, such as a typo in the name of the entity. They would invalidate the record and create a new one. But, invalidate something that has been “registered” does not sound right.

### 3 Keep looking

Try to dig more in the domain (event storming) and find the real events that brought the entities into existence even if these events are of no use in the problem that needs to be solved.

```
TankBuiltRecorded
PipeBuiltRecorded, PipeDeliveredRecorded
FacilityArea<something_meaningful>Recorded
TankDestroyedRecorded, TankDecommissionedRecorded
PipeDecommissionedRecorded
FacilityArea<something_meaningful>Recorded
```

Answer (score 1):

A caution

```
TankFilled
TankFilledReported
TankFilledReportSubmitted
TankFilledReportSubmissionReceived
```

Think carefully about whether the increased precision is motivated by business value.

> Therefore, what would be the correct DDD way to design an event that represents the fact that there is a tank, a pipe or an area in the production facility?

What is the business doing today?  Is there already a process in place for tracking the lifetime of the hardware in the plant (a maintenance log, perhaps?)  There's likely to be vocabulary in that place that gives you ideas as to what spellings would make sense in the code.

> Events are facts and you cannot change the past.

That's true - but you can *back date* events.  The effective date of the information is often distinct from the reported date of information.

> I do need a way for my users to invalidate a record in which they made a mistake such as a typo.

Yes - error correction is an important part of the process that you are modeling.

You should probably review Greg Young's talk [Answering a Question](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/5437-answering-a-question#video), which was based on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/dddcqrs/scheduling$20for$20things$20to$20happen%7Csort:date/dddcqrs/kmOHLymodSI/goSdXKYVhiMJ).  It's a discussion of capturing and modeling of temporality.

Here's the good news: you are running into the *right* problem.  Because you are capturing information about an external system, there are going to be opportunities for errors and conflicts, and you need to (a) figure out the protocols for addressing them, and then (b) model that process correctly.  That might include exception reports generated by the system when it observes conflicting information, or compensating events, or even automated conflict resolution (for the easy cases -- see also [Stop Over Engineering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRr4xeMn1uU)).

Comment: Thanks. I added some details to my question after reading your answer. Also, if that helps, we have no system or process to manage the lifetime of the hardware.

Comment: +1 "What is the business doing today? ...There's likely to be vocabulary in that place."  Consider it an extension of the Ubiquitous Language, and it will help tie your code to the domain.